# Swift playground runs as I type. How to change it?

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

Every time I type something into the Swift playground, the program runs as I type. Is there any way I can change a setting so that it only runs when I click the run button?

Answer (score 9):

Click on the run button until it shows Automatically run and Manually run, choose Manually.

Answer (score 1):

there should be a button on the lower left hand corner. Hold it and choose manually run as the comment above also says. Hope this helps :)